# Tkinter - memory leak arising from "Frame.pack"

Tags: python, tkinter, memory-leaks

I have a TKinter application (running on MacOS, M1 laptop) that allows you to select a video or livestream, and play it in an adjacent frame.

When it's a livestream, there is no need for "video progress" slider, so I hide it.

Here is the critical code:

```
class DetectionVideoPlayer:
   ...
   def __init__(self, ): 
       self.progress_status_bar = tk.Frame(...)

    def _reset_ui_widgets(self, is_live: bool = False):
        self._progress_status_bar.pack_forget()
        if not is_live:
            self._progress_status_bar.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=True, side=tk.BOTTOM)
```

Now, when transitioning from a livestream (`is_live=True`), to a video (`is_live=False`), My entire application freezes and I get this rapid memory leak which (if I don't kill the process) will actually freeze the computer.  Commenting out `self._progress_status_bar.pack(...)` gets rid of the leak.  The line `self._progress_status_bar.pack(...)` is actually executed fairly quickly and the interpreter passes by it, the application freezes thereafter (I presume on the next draw cycle).

I'm trying to understand why this is happening.  Does anyone here understand why calling `Frame.pack` can freeze the application, and why it can cause a (very rapid, like 1GB every 5s or so) memory leak?

Comment: `pack` by itself can't cause a memory leak since it doesn't allocate any memory. It's impossible to reproduce your problem with the code you provided. Do you have any bindings on the `<Configure>` event for any widgets, or do you possibly create multiple instances of `DetectionVideoPlayer`?

Comment: Yes I've had difficulty reproducing it with a more minimal example.
Yes, there is actually a widget within this one that does have a `<Configure>` callback (calling a redraw), which may be related.  Fact remains though (see solution) that unpacking/repacking the children of this widget fixes the leak.

Answer (score 0):

Got it (thank you GPT-4 for the suggestion).

The problem arose from the children of `self.progress_status_bar` (who had been packed in `__init__`).  When I change the code in `_reset_ui_widgets` to also call `.pack_forget()` on the children, and then repack them when appropriate, the freezing and memory leak problems go away.